# How to include and exclude checkboxes from being calculated? Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, checkbox

I was wondering if there is a way I can write a code where I have 6 checkboxes and I want to have them calculated as a final sum, I want to write it to have the selected ones included into the calculation only. I asked my teacher about it and all I got was the we did this in class crap but no we didn't, he sent me this code to use but it's not excluding the checkboxes it's all or nothing.

```
    private void jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
if (jCheckBox1.isSelected() == true) {jCheckBox1.setText("50");}
    }                                          

    private void jCheckBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
if (jCheckBox2.isSelected() == true) {jCheckBox2.setText("50");}
    }                                          

    private void jCheckBox3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
if (jCheckBox3.isSelected() == true) {jCheckBox3.setText("50");}

    }                                          

    private void jCheckBox4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
if (jCheckBox4.isSelected() == true) {jCheckBox4.setText("50");}
    }                                          

    private void jCheckBox5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
if (jCheckBox5.isSelected() == true) {jCheckBox5.setText("50");}
    }                                          

    private void jCheckBox6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
if (jCheckBox6.isSelected() == true) {jCheckBox6.setText("50");}
    }
```

And then he told me to declare variables so I did what he told me in this code

```
double Box1, Box2, Box3, Box4, Box5, Box6;
Box1 = Double.parseDouble(jCheckBox1.getText());
Box2 = Double.parseDouble(jCheckBox2.getText());
Box3 = Double.parseDouble(jCheckBox3.getText());
Box4 = Double.parseDouble(jCheckBox4.getText());
Box5 = Double.parseDouble(jCheckBox5.getText());
Box6 = Double.parseDouble(jCheckBox6.getText());
sum = Box1+Box2+Box3+Box4+Box5+Box6;
```

I have tried getting it into the next form with a few selected boxes but all I get is a huge red error and it's getting me frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See,you are defining the cases--- if the `checkboxes` have been selected, but what about them if they aren't selected!These might be picking some Garbage values as per your bottom piece of code!

So,you better provide an else statement along with each if-statement. Also,there is no need to write actionPerformed() for each of the Checkboxes! It would be achieved even using a single JButton.Else you'll have several problems implementing that as to how to set Default values and all!

You can try this.I think it'll work fine. :-

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  Double cb1,cb2,cb3,cb4,cb5,cb6;
  Double total=0d;
  if (jCheckBox1.isSelected() == true) {jCheckBox1.setText("50");}
   else jCheckBox1.setText("");
  if (jCheckBox2.isSelected() == true) {jCheckBox2.setText("50");}
   else jCheckBox2.setText("");
  if (jCheckBox3.isSelected() == true) {jCheckBox3.setText("50");}
   else jCheckBox3.setText("");
  if (jCheckBox4.isSelected() == true) {jCheckBox4.setText("50");}
   else jCheckBox4.setText("");
  if (jCheckBox5.isSelected() == true) {jCheckBox5.setText("50");}
   else jCheckBox5.setText("");
  if (jCheckBox6.isSelected() == true) {jCheckBox6.setText("50");}
   else jCheckBox6.setText("");
  cb1=Double.parseDouble((jCheckBox1.getText().equals(""))?"0":"50");
  cb2=Double.parseDouble((jCheckBox2.getText().equals(""))?"0":"50");
  cb3=Double.parseDouble((jCheckBox3.getText().equals(""))?"0":"50");
  cb4=Double.parseDouble((jCheckBox4.getText().equals(""))?"0":"50");
  cb5=Double.parseDouble((jCheckBox5.getText().equals(""))?"0":"50");
  cb6=Double.parseDouble((jCheckBox6.getText().equals(""))?"0":"50");
  total=cb1+cb2+cb3+cb4+cb5+cb6;
  jLabel1.setText("The total comes out to be :- "+total);    
}
```

[image: Output on Running Code]

Comment: if I want the total to come in a label in another form what do I do?

Comment: Just pass the Result as a String to another Class in a new JFrame!

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to figure out how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Use an else in your Ifs and set the text to "0" if it's not selected.

Also, when you initialize your checkboxes, set a default text of "0".